# How can I write an array of struct of 20 structs despite not being entirely populated?

Tags: c, struct, file-io, io, fwrite

This is my struct:

```
typedef struct file {
    char name[20];
    int size;
    int offset;
} file;
```

So basically I'm writing

```
4bytes for num of files
array of structs --> each 28 bytes
contents of files
```

```
// writing num of files
    fwrite(&numFiles, sizeof(numFiles), 1, binFile);

    size_t bytesW = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i  < MAX; i++) {
        // writing structs of information
        bytesW += fwrite(list, sizeof(file), 1, binFile);
    }
    printf("bytes written: %d\n", bytesW);
    fclose(binFile);
```

Is it possible to write the entire array, if I only have a couple struct elements filled? I want to do this so that whenever I want to add new elements I can fseek into the end of dir with `sizeof(file) * numFiles`.

**EDIT** This is for a binary file

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to write your entire array to a file even if only some of it is filled with meaningful data.

To avoid undefined behavior, I recommend that you at least initialize everything in the array before writing it to the file.  You can simply run `memset` after allocating the memory for the array in order to initialize everything to 0, or if your array is allocated as a global variable then it will get initialized to 0 automatically.

The code you provided looks like it just writes the same element every time.  Maybe you meant to use `&list[i]` instead of `list`.

Comment: like initialize to 0?

Comment: Yes, initializing to 0 is fine, and a pretty standard thing to do.

Comment: writing it that way is giving me 00 all throughout. Can I use do it w/o a for loop like `fwrite(list, sizeof(file), MAX, binFile);`?

Comment: You don't need a for loop, but for loops are a good way to do it.  The line of code you quoted has a problem.  As I already explained in my answer, it writes the same element every time, because `list` is not changing.  Please see my answer.  I suspect you are just not setting the data correctly or not writing it to the file correctly, but I can't give you any useful answers about why you are getting "00 all throughout" unless you provide a [mcve].  How about you accept my answer and then start a new question with your code and details about why it's not working?